# For very large numbers math.log10() seems to work but math.log() doesnt seem to work, why is that so?

Tags: python, math

The question is that a number is given in the form of a string. We have to check whether it is a power of 2 or not. where it should be greater than 2. Accordingly we have to return 0 or 1.

```
class Solution:
# @param A : string
# @return an integer
def power(self, A):
    if (int(A)<2):
        return 0
    val=int(A)
    check=math.log(val)/math.log(2)
    if (math.floor(check)==math.ceil(check)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

This returns 0 for "5070602400912917605986812821504" whereas if I use math.log10() instead of math.log(), or if I directly use math.log2(). It returns 1.

Comment: you're doing in incorrectly. To check if a number is a power of 2 use `a = int(A); return a & (a - 1) == 0`

Comment: Float numbers have limited precision. So result of log or another floating-point operation might differ a bit from expected exact value. You may get result like 99.9999999999997 instead of 100, so your comparison of ceil and floor will be failed.